# Why do important system processes exhibit lower valued priorities?

Tags: system, process-priority

I'm still learning about Linux.

As a Linux distro, Ubuntu is blessed with the ability to multi-task, the concurrent execution of programs. And these programs have processes, taking up their chunk of the system resources as necessary.

Process scheduling allows the execution of processes by priorities, so that the higher valued priorities execute more often that the lower valued priorities.  But it is a surprise to me that the very important processes actually exhibit lower valued priorities. Why is this the case?  What are the benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux, processes with lower priorities are executed with a more favourable schedule. It can range from -20 (processes are given the best treatment) to 20 (they are less favoured by the kernel). You can check [nice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) man page for more info.

So important process have low priority so that they will be favoured over normal processes.

Comment: But why do some utilities try to correct this by giving the important processes higher valued priorities?

Comment: Which utility does this?